# How many unordered pairs $A$ and $B$ are there?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

Let $S=\{1,2,3,...,10\}$ . How many unordered pairs $A$ and $B$ are there, where $A$ and $B$ are non empty disjoint subsets of $S$ ?

Any approach for such questions ?

---

[Total number of unordered pairs of disjoint subsets of S](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1223425/total-number-of-unordered-pairs-of-disjoint-subsets-of-s?noredirect=1&lq=1)

This is one related question, but using the same approach as given in the above link, I am getting

$\left(\frac{3^n - 1}{2} + 1 \right) - 2^n$ for my question

---

But, I need a confirmation here ?

Comment: Yes.  There are $2^n$ unordered pairs of subsets where one of the subsets is the empty set.

Comment: I'm getting the same result as yours. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We reformulate the problem somewhat and verify OPs formula
\begin{align*}
\frac{3^n - 1}{2} + 1 - 2^n
\end{align*}
by  showing that the  question asks  in  fact for   famous numbers.

> We consider  the set $S_n=\{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$ and ask for the number of *non-empty* partitions of the set 
>   \begin{align*}
> S_{n+1}=S_n\cup\{n+1\}
> \end{align*}
>   into *three* non-empty 
>   sets.

Note, this number is the same as OPs question  is  asking  for, because whenever we consider an unordered pair $(A,B)$ with $A,B\subset S_n,  A\cap B=\emptyset$ we have one of two cases:

- $A\cup B=S_n$: This corresponds to  the partition $S_{n+1}=A\cup B\cup\{n+1\}$ and vice versa.
- $A\cup B \ne S_n$: This corresponds to the partition $S_{n+1}=A\cup B\cup \left(S_{n+1}\setminus (A\cup B)\right)$ and vice versa.

The number of ways of partitioning a set of $n$ elements into $k$ nonempty sets is called *[Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind)* and denoted with ${n\brace k}$. They admit the  *[representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Explicit_formula)*
\begin{align*}
{n\brace k}=\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^k(-1)^{k-j}\binom{k}{j}j^n
\end{align*}

> Here we are looking for ${n+1\brace 3}$, the number of ways of partitioning a set of $n+1$ elements into $3$ nonempty sets. We obtain for $n>0$:
>   \begin{align*}
> {n+1\brace 3}&=\frac{1}{3!}\sum_{j=1}^3(-1)^{3-j}\binom{3}{j}j^{n+1}\\
> &=\frac{1}{6}\left(\binom{3}{1}1^{n+1}-\binom{3}{2}2^{n+1}+\binom{3}{3}3^{n+1}\right)\\
> &=\frac{1}{2}\left(3^{n}+1\right)-2^n
> \end{align*}
>   which coincides with OPs result.

*Note:* The sequence $$\left({n\brace 3}\right)_{n\geq 0}=(0,0,0,1, 6, 25, 90, 301, 966, 3025, 9330, 28501,\ldots)$$ is archived in OEIS as *[A000392](http://oeis.org/A000392)*.

Answer (score 2):

First assume that we need ordered pairs $A$ and $B$, where $A$ and $B$ are disjoint subsets of $S$. For this, an element can either go to A or B or to neither of them. There are $3^n$ ways of doing this.

Now let's remove the case when A or B is empty.
Case 1: One is empty, other is not. There are $2 \times (2^n - 1)$ such cases.
Case 2: Both are empty: There is only $1$ such case.
We need to remove these $ 2^{n+1} - 1 $ cases from $3^n$.

So we are left with $3^n - 2^{n+1} + 1$ possibilities.

But since we need unordered pairs of $A$ and $B$, we divide this by $2$ to get $\boxed{\frac{3^n + 1}{2} - 2^n}$.

One approach for solving such questions is to start with a broader case that has less restrictions and then apply restrictions on it.

Comment: @MarkusScheuer fixed mistake.

Comment: Well done! (+1)

Comment: @shauryagupta Thanks for confirming :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof of your second question.

Consider a set $E$ containing $n$ elements ($\mathrm{card}(E)=n$) and $q=\mathrm{card}(F)$ where :

$$F=\{(A,B)\in\mathcal{P}(E)^2;\,A\cap B=\emptyset\}$$

Since the single subset $A$ of $E$ verifying $A\cap A=\emptyset$ is $\emptyset$ itself, the answer to your question will be $1+\frac{q-1}{2}$.

Since the elements of $F$ can be classified according to their cardinal, we have :

$$F=\bigcup_{k=0}^nF_k\qquad\mathrm{where}\quad F_k=\{(A,B)\in\mathcal{P}_k(E)^2;\,A\cap B=\emptyset\}$$

where $\mathcal{P}_k(E)$ denotes the set of all subsets of $E$ whose cardinal is $k$.

This is the union of pairwise disjoint sets, and therefore :

$$q=\sum_{k=0}^n\mathrm{card}(F_k)$$

We see that $\mathrm{card}(F_k)={n\choose k}2^{n-k}$. Thus :

$$q=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}2^{n-k}=3^n$$

Finally, there are $1+\frac{3^n-1}{2}$ unordered pairs of disjoint subsets.

Comment: It seems your formula should be revised.  When setting $n=2$ it produces $5$ instead of $1$, when setting $n=3$ it produces $14$ instead of $6$.

Comment: @Markus Scheuer : I don't see what's wrong with the case $n=2$. Consider  $E=\{a,b\}$; here are the $5$ unordered pairs of disjoint subsets of $E$ : $\{\emptyset,\emptyset\}$,  $\{\emptyset,\{a\}\}$, $\{\emptyset,\{b\}\}$, $\{\emptyset,\{a,b\}\}$, $\{\{a\},\{b\}\}$.

Comment: We are looking for *non-empty* subsets $A,B$. Here we consider  $\{\{a\},\{b\}\}$ as the only solution.

Comment: Ok, so I have to subtract the $2^n$ pairs of the form $\{\emptyset,A\}$ for any $A\subset E$, which leads to $1+\frac{3^n-1}{2}-2^n$.

Comment: Yup! In fact OPs formula is correct. :-)

Comment: @MarkusScheuer Thanks :-)

Comment: @JonGarrick: You're welcome! :-)

Comment: @MarkusScheuer, Jon Garrick - In didn't meant that the OP was wrong :-) Just proposed a proof of what I had understood.

Comment: @epi163sqrt Can you show me $6$ cases when $n=3$ because I am getting Only $5$ unordered Disjoint Non-empty Pair.

Comment: @mathophile: We have six partitions, each consists of a two-element subset and two one-element subsets. In compact notation: $(1,2|3|4),(1,3|2|4),(1,4|2|3),(2,3|1|4),(2,4|1|3),(3,4|1|2)$.