# How many unordered pairs of $\{A,B\}$ of subsets are possible under given conditions?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Let $S=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. Find the number of unordered pairs $\{A,B\}$ of subsets of $S$ usch that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, where $A$ and $B$ or both may be empty.

This question here [[1]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2111793/how-many-unordered-pairs-a-and-b-are-there) addreses a similar kind of problem but it doesn't take empty sets into consideration.

***My Approach:***

Let us select subset $A$ first which would mean that the selection of subset $B$ depends on $A$.

Let $n(A)$ denote the number of elements in subset $A$. Suppose $n(A)=k$, then the subset $B$ has control over the selection of remaining $(n-k)$ elements which means that the number of such possible pairs $=\binom{n}{k}2^{n-k}$

$$\therefore \text {Total unordered pairs} =\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}2^{n-k}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{n-k}2^{n-k}$$
$$=(1+2)^n=3^n$$

I just want to verify my solution. So please check for any mistakes in my solution and please offer suggestions.

***THANKS***

**Correction**: These are the total number of ORDERED pairs including both sets empty case. As stated by Phicar in the answer, to keep the both sets empty case in the unordered pairs as well, it may be excluded before and can be added later, hence giving the total number of unordered pairs to be $\dfrac{3^n-1}{2}+1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful, you are taking an order by saying "Let us select subset $A$".
  For example, if $n=1$ you are counting $3.$ Mainly: $(\{1\},\emptyset),(\emptyset,\{1\}),(\emptyset,\emptyset).$ So you will have to take out the order. Notice that you can not just divide by $2$ because one of the cases is the empty set twice. So take it out, divide  by $2$ and add it later:
$$\frac{3^n-1}{2}+1.$$

Comment: I got the point when you took out $1$ from the $3^n$ cases but will you please explain why did you divide by two again? I'm sorry

Comment: I'm really sorry. I actually got confused between ordered pairs and unordered pairs. You are absolutely correct.

Comment: No worries, glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

For any $x \in S$, we have three possibilities:

- $x \in A$, but $x \not\in B$
- $x \in B$, but $x \not\in A$
- $x \not\in A$ and $x \not\in B$

This gives $3^n$ *ordered* pairs of disjoint subsets of $S$. To get unordered pairs, we have to treat the case where $A=B=\emptyset$ differently from the case where $A \neq B$.

The resulting number of unordered pairs is thus $\frac{3^n-1}{2}+1$.