# Finding the number of possible subsets for triple subset

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

This question was inspired from : [Total number of unordered pairs of disjoint subsets of S](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1223425/total-number-of-unordered-pairs-of-disjoint-subsets-of-s)

> Question: Let $S=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.Find the total number of unordered triple of disjoint subsets of S.

I solved this question using Stirling numbers of second kind and found $715$.However , when i want to solve it using the technique in given link , i failed . When i used it , i found $$\frac{4^6-1}{3!} +1=683.5$$ What am i missing ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note:  any such selection is associated with a map from $S\to \{A,B,C, D\}$, where the map indicates which set the element goes into (and $D$, say, denote "none").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem arises in trying to handle the cases in which one or more of your sets are empty.

Let's do it for a general $n$ (in your case, $n=6$).  Thus, let $S[n]=\{1, \cdots n\}$

We get an ordered triple of disjoint subsets of $S[n]$ via a function $$F:S[n]\to \{A,B,C,D\}$$

Where $A,B,C$ denote the desired three disjoint subsets, and $D$ denotes the elements of $S_n$ which do not appear in any of your sets.

There are, of course, $4^n$ of these.

Now, to handle the symmetry, let's first remove the case in which each of $A,B,C$ is empty.  Of course, that is $1$ case.

Then, we remove the cases in which exactly $2$ of your three sets are empty.  There are $3\times (2^n-1)$ such cases.

The remaining cases are all distinct, so give rise to $$\frac {4^n-3\times (2^n-1)-1}{3!}$$ unordered triples.

The ordered triples with exactly two empty sets give rise to $$\frac {3\times (2^n-1)}3=2^n-1$$ unordered triples

And of course the case where all three are empty give rise to $1$ unordered triple.  Thus the final answer is $$\boxed {\frac {4^n-3\times (2^n-1)-1}{3!}+2^n}$$