Total number of unordered pairs of disjoint subsets of S is equal to?
Here the set taken for example is $S={1,2,3,4}$
I know that the formula for this is simple and it is $\frac {3^n+1} {2}$ but I can't understand it. I know there are solutions for this thing in the same website, but I want an easier explanation.

To clarify are you asking for the number of pairs $(A,B)$ of subsets of $S$ such that $A\cap B=\varnothing$ and where we do not distinguish between $(A,B)$ and $(B,A)$?

Is this the answer that satisfy you? https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1223442/1204204

@RupertRybka I saw that answer before posting my question, and I couldn't understand the process.

@AnCar Exactly, We do not distinguish between $(A, B)$ and $(B, A)$. Which means it gives us {A,B.}

Ok, up to which moment you CAN understand the solution that I mentioned? Moreover, where did you get this problem from?

This is just a restating of the argument in Total number of unordered pairs of disjoint subsets of S, perhaps with a bit of clarification.
Let $S$ have $n$ elements. In order to obtain an ordered pair of subsets, each element in $S$ can be individually assigned to the first subset, the second subset or neither of the subsets. This means that to each ordered pair of subsets $(A,B)$ we can associate a unique function $\phi_{A,B}:S\to\{0,1,2\}$ where $\phi_{A,B}(x)=0$ if
$x$ is in neither of the subsets, $1$ if $x$ is in $A$ but not in $B$ and $2$ if $x\in B\setminus A$.
Clearly the total number of such functions is $|\{0,1,2\}|^{|S|}=3^n$. This is the number of ordered pairs $(A,B)$. So what if we want the unordered pairs? Well we are identifying $(A,B)$ with $(B,A)$, so we should divide by $2$. This is indeed the case with one exception, namely the pair $(\varnothing,\varnothing)$, that is unchanged by reordering the elements of the tuple.
So the number of unordered pairs is $\tfrac{3^n +1}{2}$.
